# Current curve (Transiesta code)

Tags: density-functional-theory, siesta

What is the difference between this figure:

[image]

and this figure:

[image]

Comment: +1 but from where did you get these figures?

Comment: The last figure is from my result, obtained by using Transiesta code. by discussing the behavior, and from literature, I remark that the experimentalist researcher got the first one based on applying a gate on a device system in graphene FET. For that, i want to know why there is a difference in terms that how the electron transport in Transiesta Code

Comment: I recommend you to look how a transistor works. One thing is the applied voltage (for the second image) and other thing is using also a gate to modify the electron density in the main channel.

Comment: I think my answer in https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9664/quantum-transport-in-device-transiesta-code/9795#9795 should already tell you that the effect of "applied voltage" and applying a gate is system specific so you should understand it in terms of your own system. As @Camps says, understanding the current curves of a transistor might help you.

Comment: Thank you very much ^^

Comment: I did not see your response to my question because you did not use the @ character to ping me. I gave my +1 long ago, but now that it has been more than 1 year, can you update us please? Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question? Did you figure it out?